# Using Timer with Windows Thread Pool

Tags: c++, winapi

I have written the following program which It should print something for 10th time. I wanted to use timer and thread pool to implement the following program but this program only show one message and then program will quit.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>


// How many seconds we'll display the message box
int g_nSecLeft = 10;

PTP_WORK g_WorkItem = NULL;

VOID CALLBACK WorkerOne(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE arg_instance, PVOID arg_context, PTP_TIMER arg_timer)
{
    std::printf("You have %d seconds to respond", --g_nSecLeft);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create the thread pool timer object
    PTP_TIMER pointer_timer = CreateThreadpoolTimer(WorkerOne, NULL, NULL);

    if (pointer_timer == NULL) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error: something goes wrong." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Start the timer in one second to trigger every 1 second
    ULARGE_INTEGER relative_start_time;
    relative_start_time.QuadPart = (LONGLONG)-(10000000); // start in 1 second
    
    FILETIME ft_relative_start_time;
    ft_relative_start_time.dwHighDateTime = relative_start_time.HighPart;
    ft_relative_start_time.dwLowDateTime = relative_start_time.LowPart;
    
    SetThreadpoolTimer(pointer_timer, &ft_relative_start_time, 1000, 0);
    
    if (IsThreadpoolTimerSet(pointer_timer))
    {
        std::cout << "Time has been set." << std::endl;
    }

    WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks(g_WorkItem, FALSE);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why it doesn't call the callback function for more than one time?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks()` is the wrong thing to do.  It waits for work items queued via [`CreateThreadpoolWork()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-createthreadpoolwork) to complete, but you're not queuing any work items, so `WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks()` returns immediately and  your program just exits.

Since you've got nothing better to do, you might as well just call `Sleep()` in the main thread. Or, you can have the main thread create an event object with [`CreateEvent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventw), then signal that event in your timer callback, and have the main thread wait for the event to be signaled.

Answer (score 1):

you can use for instance next code

```
struct TimerData 
{
    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0);
    LONG n;

    ~TimerData()
    {
        if (hEvent) CloseHandle(hEvent);
    }

    TimerData(ULONG n) : n(n) {}

    static VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(
        __inout      PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE /*Instance*/,
        __inout_opt  PVOID Context,
        __inout      PTP_TIMER Timer
        )
    {
        DbgPrint("TimerCallback(%d)\n", reinterpret_cast<TimerData*>(Context)->n);
        if (!InterlockedDecrementNoFence(&reinterpret_cast<TimerData*>(Context)->n))
        {
            SetThreadpoolTimer(Timer, 0, 0, 0);
            SetEvent(reinterpret_cast<TimerData*>(Context)->hEvent);
        }
    }
};

void TimerDemo(ULONG n)
{
    if (TimerData* p = new TimerData(n))
    {
        if (p->hEvent)
        {
            if (PTP_TIMER Timer = CreateThreadpoolTimer(TimerData::TimerCallback, p, 0))
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER li = { (ULONG)-10000000, -1};
                SetThreadpoolTimer(Timer, (PFILETIME)&li, 1000, 0);

                WaitForSingleObject(p->hEvent, INFINITE);
                CloseThreadpoolTimer(Timer);
            }
        }
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible to repeat task instead of closing timer? Thanks